# `st_geomfromgeojson` throwing invalid hexdigit error?

Tags: postgis

I'm attempting to create a geometry from geojson using postgis.  I'm getting a cryptic error that isn't very informative about how to fix this.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT st_geomfromgeojson('{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        -101.15663846469602,
        40.37646152866321
      ],
      [
        -108.74819119907102,
        40.37646152866321
      ],
      [
        -108.74819119907102,
        37.04267167068658
      ],
      [
        -101.15663846469602,
        37.04267167068658
      ]
    ]
  ]
}');
```

I'm getting back an error about an invalid hex digit:

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: Invalid hex digit: 'P'
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.data.PostgreGeometryValueHandler.makeGeometryFromPGGeometry(PostgreGeometryValueHandler.java:200)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.data.PostgreGeometryValueHandler.getValueFromObject(PostgreGeometryValueHandler.java:122)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.data.PostgreGeometryValueHandler.fetchColumnValue(PostgreGeometryValueHandler.java:58)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.data.handlers.JDBCAbstractValueHandler.fetchValueObject(JDBCAbstractValueHandler.java:49)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetDataReceiver.fetchRow(ResultSetDataReceiver.java:126)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.fetchQueryData(SQLQueryJob.java:798)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:609)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:486)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:173)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:493)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:894)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3726)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:173)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4982)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid hex digit: 'P'
    at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKBReader.hexToInt(WKBReader.java:96)
    at org.locationtech.jts.io.WKBReader.hexToBytes(WKBReader.java:84)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.data.PostgreGeometryValueHandler.makeGeometryFromWKB(PostgreGeometryValueHandler.java:145)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.data.PostgreGeometryValueHandler.makeGeometryFromWKT(PostgreGeometryValueHandler.java:226)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ext.postgresql.model.data.PostgreGeometryValueHandler.makeGeometryFromPGGeometry(PostgreGeometryValueHandler.java:197)
    ... 17 more
```

How do I fix this query, and what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

The co-ordinate list is malformed, and will return an error of type "Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring". That is probably the cause of the error message "Invalid hex digit: 'P'", where 'P' is the first digit of the actual error message.

To create a valid list of co-ordinates, the last co-ordinate pair in the list must exactly match the first (thereby closing the Polygon). The following statement should therefore work:

```
SELECT st_geomfromgeojson('{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        -101.15663846469602,
        40.37646152866321
      ],
      [
        -108.74819119907102,
        40.37646152866321
      ],
      [
        -108.74819119907102,
        37.04267167068658
      ],
      [
        -101.15663846469602,
        37.04267167068658
      ],
      [
        -101.15663846469602,
        40.37646152866321
      ]
    ]
  ]
}');
```